# Get remote IP in express in WSL2

Tags: node.js, windows, express, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a simple Express server running in Node.js on WSL2 (my home server). The listening port is forwarded from the router to the Windows machine and then to Ubuntu (WSL2). As far as I understand it, since all my traffic is forwarded, I can only rely on the 'x-forwarded-for' header, since otherwise I'll just get the last forwarder in my chain (a Windows virtual adapter). Unfortunately, 'x-forwarded-for' is always undefined, probably because Windows won't populate that when forwarding. Is there any solution to this? Code below for reference, thank you!

```
const vEthernet_Adapter = 'x.x.x.x';

app.set('trust proxy', vEthernet_Adapter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    console.log('ip: ', ip);
})
```

Comment: `As far as I understand it, since all my traffic is forwarded, I can only rely on the 'x-forwarded-for' header, since otherwise I'll just get the last forwarder in my chain (windows virtual adapter).` This only applies to HTTP proxies.

Comment: @tkausl: The problem applies to TCP proxies as well as HTTP proxies.  The fix (look at header added by proxy) only works for HTTP proxies, since TCP proxies know nothing about HTTP headers.  So the solution will be to use an HTTP proxy such as nginx running in Windows, and not use TCP-layer proxy to expose the WSL service to the router.